# Can Emacs ignore change of timestamp of git stashed file?

Tags: git, emacs

I have written a small function in Emacs that does a

```
git stash
git stash apply
```

in the Git repository of the file I visit, and I have added this function
in `after-save-hook` so it runs every time I save the file. The problem is
that when I save the file, the git commands above run and change the timestamp, 
so Emacs thinks that the file has been modified outside Emacs itself. Naturally, when I try to edit the
file again (without closing and re-opening) Emacs asks if I want to really edit the buffer which is quite annoying.

Any ideas on how to make Emacs not think that the file has been changed as
a result of the above git commands?

EDIT: Thanks jvasak. Adding `(revert-buffer nil t t)` at the end of my function
did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure that this would work, but you could add `revert-buffer` to your `after-save-hook` which should reload the file from disk.  Combined with the `revert-without-query` trick from the [GNU Emacs Manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_121.html), this may provide the desired behavior.